# Можно ли пробросить несколько видеокарт на несколько виртуальных машин на одном компьютере?

Tags: gpu, виртуальная-машина

Допустим, у меня есть четыре видеокарты, я создаю на компе четыре виртуальные машины, и мне нужно на каждую виртуальную машину пробросить по одной видеокарте, чтобы я там мог использовать GPU.

Возможно ли такое, и если да, то есть ли у вас на примере подобные гайды (именно с несколькими виртуальными машинами)?

Comment: Да, возможно. Работали с удаленными ВМ с данными Oxford Nanopore, там требуется видеокарта для бейзколлирования. Как детально сделано, - не знаю, скорее всего через GPU pass-through.

Comment: xen вроде позволяет это делать